# GAE Javascript Client : Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT `https://apis.google.com/js/client.js`

Has anyone experiencing it right now? 
Suddenly, the google cloud endpoint - javascript client stopped working. Is it replaced or being maintained? 
If so, why is it I haven't receive an email or any means of notification?

**EDIT**

Anyway, what are the ways to catch this error?

**UPDATE 1:**
For unknown reason, GAE - Javascript Client is working again. I am now trying to catch the error so that we can notify the users; and hope this would not happen again.

**UPDATE 2:**
Doesn't work again. I suspect maintenance is going on(If this is true), What disappoint me is that they failed to provide prior notice.

**UPDATE 3:**
It is now working as expected. Few updates were made that has nothing to do with the error.

Comment: Works for me. Is it your local network?

Comment: it's on production and we haven't touch anything for a couple of days

Comment: Your web browser is the client requesting https://apis.google.com/js/client.js not your app engine server. The error you posted sounds like one that the Google Chrome dev tools outputs when it cannot reach a host.

Comment: Ok. I understand, so is it possible that the host was blocked by our network?

Comment: That would be my first guess.

Comment: Thanks, I'll to debug it on other network.

Comment: I think this not a local network problem, just a few minutes ago the problem is gone, no one changed anything. My guess, some sort of maintenance happened.

Comment: Were/are you by any chance using Chrome with QUIC enabled?

Comment: I don't fully understand QUIC but if it is enabled in Chrome by default, I might be using. There was an error that has a _QUIC_ word on it, I din't look into detail assuming that it has no important factors, if it has, could you tell me?